# Multiple Attributes from one Query

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I am having a problem getting multiple attributes for one item. Below is my Table:

**Table: product_attrib**

```
id | product_id | name | value 
------------------------------
 0 |         33 | age  |   25
 1 |         33 | size |   25
```

My problem is when I join the query, I only get one of the attributes with such a query:

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    p.*
    ,pa.name
    ,pa.value
FROM product AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_attrib AS pa ON (
    p.id = pa.product_id
)
```

**My Results**

```
"products_id":"0",
"products_price":"0.0000",
"products_name":null,
"products_description":null,
"attrib_name":"color",
"attrib_value":"red"
```

*Do you see how I only get one attribute set?* 
Is there a way I can get **all** the attributes for a product?

Comment: This is confusing question. Please rewrite your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your original query is right as it is. You probably want the product, no matter if attributes can be found.

You *can* reverse the order of the tables in the `JOIN` to prevent losing rows from `product_attrib` like this (if `product` with `product_id` 33 does not exist):

```
SELECT
     p.*
    ,pa.name
    ,pa.value
FROM product_attrib AS pa 
LEFT JOIN product AS p ON p.id = pa.product_id
```

But that's probably not what you want.

A **`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`** includes all rows from the left hand table and adds values from the right table where the JOIN condition can be fulfilled (potentially creating multiple rows if multiple matches are found in the right hand table.) If no matching row can be found in the right hand table NULL values are substituted for all columns of the right hand table.
Start by [reading the manual here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

If you want "all attributes" per product in the same row, you need to [**aggregate** values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
      ,group_concat(pa.name) AS att_names
      ,group_concat(pa.value) AS att_values
FROM  product AS p
LEFT  JOIN product_attrib AS pa ON p.id = pa.product_id
WHERE p.product_id = 33
GROUP BY p.*;
```

Comment: Ah, Aggregate was what I was missing! Thank you so much, I appreciate the time you gave me to answer this :)

Answer (score -2):

i see so many people writing full joins when they aren't necessary.  please correct me if i'm wrong.

```
SELECT 
    p.*
    ,pa.name
    ,pa.value
FROM product AS p, product_attrib AS pa
WHERE p.id = pa.product_id
```

Comment: You are wrong in two ways: 1) This is not a LEFT JOIN. 2) Explicit JOIN syntax is the proper way to do it in any case.

Comment: Why is a left join required?  Is there documentation stating that a JOIN is more proper?  This accomplishes the exact same thing with less code (albeit if a product has no attributes it will return nothing).

Comment: This accomplishes the exact same thing with an `INNER JOIN`, not the same as a `LEFT JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` is needed if we want to show products that have no attributes. Less code, no. I count the same amount of code. Documentation is the SQL-92 standard, already 19 years old.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I do need a LEFT JOIN to show results that don't have matches (Said above) :)